# UIImagePickerController recorded video flipped with UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

```
    self.MovieInterface =   [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.MovieInterface.delegate    =   self;
    self.MovieInterface.sourceType  =   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.MovieInterface.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    self.MovieInterface.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    self.MovieInterface.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    self.MovieInterface.videoMaximumDuration    =   30;
    self.MovieInterface.allowsEditing = YES;

    self.MovieInterface.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;

    [self.view addSubview:self.MovieInterface.view];
```

The video is constantly flipped horizontally. I tried to look up other similar issues with images, but I couldnt find anything regarding video recording.Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: It's not an issue, it's normal behavior for cameras designed to shoot self. Just like the webcams. You can shoot some text to understand why.